# Java Regex-based string replacement

Tags: java, xml, regex, groovy

Looking for a regex based String replacement in Java on the below use-case.
I'm doing some Groovy based XML processing and due to some custom processing (won't go much in detail on this), the resulting XML has some invalid tags, for e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Customer id="xyz" xmlns='http://abc.com'>
<order orderGroup="mock">
    <entry>
        <key>test</key>
    </entry>
</order orderGroup="mock">
</Customer id="xyz">
```

If you note, the end tags of the element names containing attributes are messed up. The XML is just treated as a string, so what I want to do is, just replace occurrences of such end tags via string regex based replacements. For e.g. replace

```
</order orderGroup="mock"> with </order>, 
</Customer id="xyz"> with </Customer>
```

Any idea if there is quick Java String based regex I can use for doing such replacements ?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you load the javadoc, hit Ctrl-F, and type "regex"? Why don't you fix the faulty "custom processing" which generates garbage instead of trying to workaround the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
    xml = xml.replaceAll("</([^ >]+).*?>", "</$1>");
```

Comment: +1, but I would have used `</([^\s>]+)[^>]+>`. `.*?` is a fickle friend; why put yourself at its mercy when you can so easily say exactly what you want?

Comment: I agree about \\s, but it seems regex converts "<e1><e2></e2></e1>" -> "<e1><e2></e></e>"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to fix your custom XML processing and have it generate **valid** XML.

The easy solution is to use something like [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to clean up your XML.

If you must use regex, you could try something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("</([A-Za-z]+) [^>]+>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);

if(matcher.find()) {
   xml = matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(1));
}
```

I haven't tested this out, so keep that in mind. There might be a few issues.

Explanation of the regex:

```
<         -> The opening angle bracket of the tag
/         -> The / that marks a closing tag
(         -> Start of a capturing group. We want to capture the actual ending tag.
[A-Za-z]+ -> One or more alphabetic characters (upper and lowercase)
)         -> End of the capturing group.
          -> A space.
[^>]+     -> One or more of anything that is not a closing angle-bracket.
>         -> The closing angle bracket of the tag.
```

Comment: Thanks Vivin! That works to an extent. Only issue is, it replaced even the start and ending angle brackets. In other words, it results in Customer instead of <Customer>

Comment: As [Evgeniy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15581822/20938) shows, this solution is much more verbose than it needs to be.  In particular, it's never necessary to call `find()` before doing the substitution. `replaceAll()` does that itself, and if there are no matches it returns the original string unchanged.  You don't need to call methods like `group(n)` for the replacement string, either.  If there happen to be any question marks or backslashes in the string you'll get a runtime exception; that's not a problem if you use `"$1"`.

Comment: Yes his answer is much better.